# Getting a method to run after refresh?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm having trouble getting my main method (or any method) to run after refreshing the page with Selenium Python. Everything including the refresh works fine, but how does one get the program to run upon refresh much like it would when first running the program from command prompt?

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'./chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@data-a-target="XXXXX"]')))

def main():
    try:
        button.click()
        (codeblock)

    #refresh upon error detection
    except Exception
        driver.refresh()

#not sure what this does but it doesn't work without it
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Note this block is missing or has changed code ex. the URL. But everything including the refresh call upon an exception works fine.

I'm really not sure how this all fits together, as I need main() to be called after refresh, though there are variables declared outside of main() that main() uses. Unsure if that raises any issues.

In short, how might one be able to make what is effectively an infinite loop (assuming main() loops when no errors occur), in that when an error occurs, the page refreshes (check), and upon refresh goes back to main()?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to run most of your `main()` function in an infinite loop.  If you want, you can `break` out of the loop once you know that you won't need to refresh again:

```py
def main():
    while True:
        try:
            button.click()
            (codeblock)
            if success_detected:
                break 

        # refresh upon error detection
        except Exception
            driver.refresh()
```

Alternatively, you could put the loop in the `if` block:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # this will run forever, unless you manually terminate it
    while True:
        main()
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem stemmed from having variables declared outside of `main()`. I put them outside because they were used in multiple methods, not just `main()`, but the issue with that was calling `main()` after a refresh was essentially asking `main()` to perform its usual code without having working variables. This triggered an exception, which triggered a refresh (refresh upon exception), which ultimately caused an infinite loop of refreshing the page. The solution was simple:

```
from selenium.webdriver.opera.options import Options

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'./chromedriver.exe, options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://www.google.com')

def main():

    try:

        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

        button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@data-a-target="XXXXX"]')))

        button.click()

    except Exception:
        driver.refresh()
        main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()`
```

Calling `main()` after `driver.refresh()` and declaring the variables within `main()` (as well as every other method that uses them) fixes the issue.